# Representation of varchars in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, enums, varchar

I have a rather large sqlite database where one column is a varchar, but takes only a few values (basically enum). Since the database file is already a few GB and is growing, I started refactoring the column to hold ids (basically foreign keys from another table where the few varchars went).

It occured to me that maybe the effort is futile; maybe sqlite handles the situation "intelligently", as opposed to naively storing each varchar along all the others.

So the question is how does sqlite handle representation of repeating varchar values in a column, and will converting from varchars to ids cut the db file size?

Comment: Will using IDs shrink the database? Probably. But the only real way to find out is to test it and find out.

Answer (score 0):

In [SQLite's internal record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format), numbers that are small enough can be stored in one byte.
String values are not compressed in any way; a five-character strings will always take five bytes (or more for non-ASCII characters).

If your varchar values are all a single ASCII character, replacing them with numbers will no improve the space taken. If they are larger, it will.